# WCF Test Client sends Null value to service when XML string entered as parameter

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

Using C#, I've been trying to receive XML as a string, from the client, in a SOAP WCF service (not my choice, it's the way the client is choosing to send it) and I couldn't get it to work correctly in the WCF Test Client. I thought that I had found the problem. I assumed that the backslashes in the closing XML Tags would cause WCF Test Client to parse incorrectly and send a null value to my service without throwing any exceptions or anything in the WCF Test Client. See the link below.

http://programmersranch.blogspot.com/2014/08/c-wcf-backslash-limitation-in-wcf-test.html

However, that does not seem to be the issue, as the slashes in XML are / slashes and the slashes that cause problems are \ slashes. Any suggestions? Here is the string I am copy + pasting into the string parameter for one of my service methods in WCF Test Client. I have escaped the quotation marks and so on to avoid issues with the string parsing, but it doesn't work even after escaping them.

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRs><ItemNonInventoryQueryRs requestID=\"SXRlbVF1ZXJ5fDEyMA==\" statusCode=\"500\" statusSeverity=\"Warn\" statusMessage=\"The query request has not been fully completed. There was a required element 'your item name' that could not be found in QuickBooks.\"/></QBXMLMsgsRs></QBXML>
```

Also, I want to point out that if I enter a string like "BOB" or "sally2135" or something that's not XML at all, it receives the string just fine. It just doesn't like the XML string.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include your c# code so we can get a better idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the solution is embarrassingly simple. Just minutes after asking a question I've been working on for a few hours now, I found the answer. Upon removing the \ before all of the quotation marks in the string, I received the XML string without a problem.